# Doesn't Google Music have its search syntax?

Tags: google-play-music

Doesn't Google Music have its search syntax?

e.g. search by added date, imagining like

```
after-addeddate:2015-04-17
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Google's search commands are not available within Google Play's search.